# Form fields value get reset without page load

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Following is my code in which i am trying to accomplish, when user clicks on the submit button then my javascript function sets all the value to null in the textfields of the form whose id='contact_form' without loading the page .  Kindly let me know how can i modify the following code to accomplish the functionality i've been trying to do.
Thanks!!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#love').click(function(e) {
            document.contact_form.name.value = '';
            alert('aloha!!');
            //stop the form from being submitted (not working fine)
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
</script>
<form name='abc' action='' id='abc' >
    <input type="submit" id='love' />
</form>
```

I have also tried the following function it worked fine but its not preventing from the page load

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function js(){
        document.contact_form.name.value = '';
        //stop the form from being submitted (NOT WORKING!!)
        preventDefault();
    }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Or you could just be nice and indent it for him. I just did that.

Comment: Does the alert work? Or what do you mean with "not working *fine*"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `onsubmit="return false;"` in the `form` tag your form will not be submitted. Unfortunately it will NEVER be submit. Unless you are not planning to submit it via AJAX you have to modify your `onsubmit` event like this:

```
<form onsubmit="return callFunction()">

function callFunction() {
    if(condition)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Technically it will not reload the form, it will send it. Assuming that the target page is the same as the original page it might look like a reload but in fact it is not.

Comment: Faizan - Yes, "return true" or not specifying at all will "submit" the form. Right now, it's just preventing the submission.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#abc").submit( function() {
  // do everything you want.
   return false; //will prevent the reload.
});
```

Comment: didn't work.... i tried this  <script type='text/javascript'>
     
     $("#abc").love( function() {
  // do everything you want.
  alert('hi');
   return false; //will prevent the reload.
});
   

</script>
<form name='abc' action='' id='abc' >
                <input type="submit" id='love'  />
    </form> 
</div>

Comment: $("#abc").love( function() <- love ? it should be "submit"

Answer (score 0):

To have a function execute when the form submits you have to do something like this;

```
<form onsubmit="return validate();">
your form here
</form>
```

Then you can have your check in a function called 'validate()' (or whatever you want to call it)

Make sure the validate() function returns true is the form is allowed to submit, or returns false if the page is not allowed to submit.

Also put id's and names on your input elements, that way you can access them much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an HTML like this :

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="submit" id='submit' value="clear above field without reloading" />
</form>
```

And you want the text field value to clear when a user submits without reloading using jQuery, then following script will be your remedy :

```
$(function(){
$('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#text').value('');
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A form can be submitted in many ways, not only by clicking on a submit buttons. You should really watch for `submit` events, and cancel them with `preventDefault` (instead of click events that might trigger the submit). See @user1359163's answer.

But you problem seem to be  `document.contact_form.name.value`. There is no property `contact_form` on the document object, so this will raise an error. The preventDefault is not executed, your form gets submitted and you never see the error. Set your debugger to "Stop on errors"!

You might want something like `document.forms["contact"]`, but I don't know your HTML. An id selector for the input element would be the better choice.